# Defining custom namespaces on routes in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.6

So Consider the following:

```
Route::middleware('web')
    ->namespace('App\Modules\Config\Controllers')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('config', ['as' => 'config.index',  'uses' => 'Config@index']);
        Route::put('config', ['as' => 'config.update', 'uses' => 'Config@update']);
        Route::patch('config', 'Config@update');
    });
```

This explodes when I hit any of these routes because:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Modules\Config\Controllers\Config does not exist
```

Is there not a way in laravel 5.6 to say: No I don't want to use `App\Http\Controllers` I want to use the namespace I specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a slash

`->namespace('\App\Modules\Config\Controllers')`

Comment: @TheWebs did you try?, I'm not a laraval user, but my answer makes sense if `namespace()` method takes into account the current namespace. If im wrong happy to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `RouteServiceProvider` you see that there exists property

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

It's your root namespase and you can change it for example:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Modules\Config\Controllers';
```

or just erase and set namespase directly in your route file for any group.