# Getting error "Target Class Not Found" while trying to use old way of calling controllers at web.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and I wanted to use the old way of calling controller and routes in `web.php`.

So instead of saying this:

```
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

I would call the Controller like this:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

So I added this to `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Route::prefix('web')
            ->middleware('web')
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') // <---------
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to be working because I'm getting this error:

**Target class [HomeController] does not exist.**

So how can I call my Controller at `web.php` like the old style which was used in Laravel 5 versions?

Comment: Decide what version do you use - tags are misleading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining custom namespaces on routes in laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054596/defining-custom-namespaces-on-routes-in-laravel-5-6)

Comment: You need to escape your slashes. Basically the boilerplate code is still in [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) you just need to uncomment line 29

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge laravel 8 is not overriding that way of declaring routes. Example code that works fine

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => 'db-notifications',
    'as' => 'notification.',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
],
function () {
    Route::get('/send-notification', 'NotificationsController@SendTestMail'])
   ->name('send');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code
`protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';`
in this file RouteServiceProvider.php